# Customize search results for Custom Post Types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I am writing a Wordpress plug-in that creates several Custom Post Types (CPT). For they have their own custom fields, that need to be displayed in the search results, I need to customize the search results output.

Do I need to write my own theme for that or is there a hook (or other way) to solve this in my plug-in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hook into `get_the_content` and `get_the_excerpt` filters and test with `is_search()` to see if you should alter the returned value or not.

Not tested, but this is the idea:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'my_search_excerpt' );
add_filter( 'get_the_content', 'my_search_excerpt' );

function my_search_excerpt( $content ) {
    if ( is_search() ) {
        $content = 'This is a search excerpt for ' . get_the_title();
        // maybe add a read more link
        // also, you can use global $post to access the current search result
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see four possibilities:

1. Create a new ([child](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)) [theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)
2. Override the search template using [filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Filter) ([`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include))
3. Use client-side code to modify the appearance (CSS / JavaScript, poor workaround)
4. Hook [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) or `the_excerpt`

The easiest way might be to copy the [`search.php` file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Search_Result_display) of your installed theme and modify it to fulfill your needs. You can then hook it in using the first or second way. The first requires you to [create a child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), the second to create a plugin. The latter might be more complex so I would suggest to create a theme (take a look at [template files of child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Template_Files) for an explanation).